# how to add line numbers to beginning of each line in string in javascript

Tags: javascript, string

I have a string like

```
Hi,
My
Name
is
Mike
```

How can I turn this into :

```
1.Hi,
2.My
3.Name
4.is
5.Mike
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [ask] link for 
more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Comment: seriously ? please try do so something before asking here. We are not a code writing service. Your question can be answered with several tricks, such as replacing newlines with newlines + counter. But you have to try something on your own first

Comment: I'm sorry, I tried to write myself and couldn't. I did not know the rules. I googled and only found answer for C and some other languages, there was no js version. I just joined today. I wish I wouldn't get this many bad points

Comment: jeez give this guy a break - perfectly valid question and his first time asking - damn

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```js
var numbered = `Hi,
My
Name
is
Mike`.split('\n').map((line, index) => `${index + 1}. ${line}`).join('\n')

console.log(numbered)
```

Breaking down the solution;

1. We take the original string and then split by the line-break character, so we get an array of strings (one per line)
2. Map is a function that allows us to apply a transformation function to every item of the array, returning a new one with the new items.
3. Map passes the current array item plus a zero based index. We concatenate the index with the current item so we get the string we expect
4. Since we still have an array (but we need a string) we use join method. Join method joins all items in the array with a given character, in this case we pass the line break character again so we have one line per item.

Comment: @user202729 sorry, I was still writing the explanation when you posted your comment. I usually post the answer then start improving it afterwards. See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String.replace()` with a RegExp that matches the lines' start ([regex101 example](https://regex101.com/r/f1XulZ/2)), and replace each with the line's number.

**Note:** regex suggested by [Thomas in his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49714971/how-to-add-line-numbers-to-beginning-of-each-line-in-string-in-javascript/49715059?noredirect=1#comment86443487_49715059).

```js
const str = `Hi,
My
Name
is
Mike`;

let i = 1;
const numbered = str.replace(/^/gm, () => `${i++}.`);

console.log(numbered)
```

Comment: first, `.` doesn't match line breaks, so you can simplify your regex to `/.+/g` but you can go one step further and match the beginning of a line without matching any characters with `/^/gm` and insert the enumeration

Comment: @Thomas - thanks. I wasn't aware of the multiline with text start behaviour.