# No WebGL output with custom blending on newest Safari / MacOS

Tags: macos, safari, webgl

I have a WebGL renderer I was using successfully for quite some time. This december with the latest MacOS update the shader output went completely blank. The system uses "deferred premultiplied alpha blending" (e.g. manual blending of colors with one step deferred to allow e.g. clip mask):

```
void blend(vec4 color) {
    //premultiplied alpha blending with deferred render
    vec4 fg = _last_rendered_color;
    _last_rendered_color = color; // deffer blending for the next step
    vec4 premultiplied_fg = vec4(fg.rgb * fg.a, fg.a);
    _current_render_color = (premultiplied_fg + _current_render_color * (1.0-fg.a));
}


void finalize() {
    blend(vec4(.0)); // finish deferred blend
    
    // convert premultiplied color to output color
    ...
}
        
void main() {        
    blend(vec4(1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0));
    finalize();
}
```

Notable is that when I do not finish my rendering with `blend(vec4(.0));` the output shows. Its as if `vec4 fg = _last_rendered_color; _last_rendered_color = color;` was somehow passing the `color` value to `fg` and the last blending step would be performed with `vec4(.0)`. Other operating systems and old MacOS work OK.

```js
const vs = `#version 300 es

precision mediump float;

// an attribute is an input (in) to a vertex shader.
// It will receive data from a buffer
in vec4 a_position;

 
// all shaders have a main function
void main() {
 
  // gl_Position is a special variable a vertex shader
  // is responsible for setting
  gl_Position = a_position;
}`

const fs = `#version 300 es
precision mediump float;

vec4 _last_rendered_color = vec4(.0);
vec4 _current_render_color = vec4(.0);
out vec4 final_color;
        
bool close(float value, float target) {
    return abs(target - value) < 0.001;
}
        
void blend(vec4 color) {
    //premultiplied alpha blending with deferred render
    vec4 fg = _last_rendered_color;
    _last_rendered_color = color; // deffer blending for the next step
    vec4 premultiplied_fg = vec4(fg.rgb * fg.a, fg.a);
    _current_render_color = (premultiplied_fg + _current_render_color * (1.0-fg.a));
}

void finalize() {
    blend(vec4(.0)); // finish deferred blend
    
    // convert premultiplied color to output color
    if (close(_current_render_color.a, 0.0)) {
        final_color = vec4(0.);
    } else {
        final_color = vec4(_current_render_color.rgb/_current_render_color.a, _current_render_color.a);
    }
}
        
void main() {        
    blend(vec4(1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0));
    finalize();
}
`
function createShader(gl, type, source) {
  var shader = gl.createShader(type);
  gl.shaderSource(shader, source);
  gl.compileShader(shader);
  var success = gl.getShaderParameter(shader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS);
  if (success) {
    
    return shader;
  }
 
  console.log(gl.getShaderInfoLog(shader));
  gl.deleteShader(shader);
  console.log(numberLines(source))
}

function createProgram(gl, vertexShader, fragmentShader) {
  var program = gl.createProgram();
  gl.attachShader(program, vertexShader);
  gl.attachShader(program, fragmentShader);
  gl.linkProgram(program);
  var success = gl.getProgramParameter(program, gl.LINK_STATUS);
  if (success) {
    return program;
  }
 
  console.log(gl.getProgramInfoLog(program));
  gl.deleteProgram(program);
}
function numberLines(str) {
            //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49714971/how-to-add-line-numbers-to-beginning-of-each-line-in-string-in-javascript
            return str.split('\n').map((line, index) => `${index + 1} ${line}`).join('\n')
        }

    const canvas = document.querySelector("#glcanvas");
    var gl = canvas.getContext("webgl2");

 // create GLSL shaders, upload the GLSL source, compile the shaders
 var vertexShader = createShader(gl, gl.VERTEX_SHADER, vs);
  var fragmentShader = createShader(gl, gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER, fs);

  // Link the two shaders into a program
  var program = createProgram(gl, vertexShader, fragmentShader);

  // look up where the vertex data needs to go.
  var positionAttributeLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "a_position");

  // Create a buffer and put three 2d clip space points in it
  var positionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();

  // Bind it to ARRAY_BUFFER (think of it as ARRAY_BUFFER = positionBuffer)
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);

  var positions = [
    0, 0,
    0, 0.5,
    0.7, 0,
  ];
  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(positions), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

  // Create a vertex array object (attribute state)
  var vao = gl.createVertexArray();

  // and make it the one we're currently working with
  gl.bindVertexArray(vao);

  // Turn on the attribute
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(positionAttributeLocation);

  // Tell the attribute how to get data out of positionBuffer (ARRAY_BUFFER)
  var size = 2;          // 2 components per iteration
  var type = gl.FLOAT;   // the data is 32bit floats
  var normalize = false; // don't normalize the data
  var stride = 0;        // 0 = move forward size * sizeof(type) each iteration to get the next position
  var offset = 0;        // start at the beginning of the buffer
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(
      positionAttributeLocation, size, type, normalize, stride, offset);

  // Tell WebGL how to convert from clip space to pixels
  gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);

  // Clear the canvas
  gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

  // Tell it to use our program (pair of shaders)
  gl.useProgram(program);

  // Bind the attribute/buffer set we want.
  gl.bindVertexArray(vao);

  // draw
  var primitiveType = gl.TRIANGLES;
  var offset = 0;
  var count = 3;
  gl.drawArrays(primitiveType, offset, count);
```

```html
<canvas id="glcanvas" width="640" height="480"></canvas>
```

The reproducible example was taken from WebGLFundamentals and the Fragment shader was modified.

Comment: If you are on the latest Safari, you should see a blank output. Otherwise, you should see a yellow triangle. I also have a case where Chrome on Sonoma failed to render.

Comment: Update: I replaced the golbal variable with function argument passed to each call in `main`. IMHO an apple-related bug...